# list files with similar names sorted by similarity

Tags: files, sort, search

Is it possible to search files and list them descending by similarity ?

e.g.:

Following files are in /:

- heo
- HELLO
- helo
- hello

When I search for 'hello' I would like to have a List like:

- hello
- HELLO
- helo
- heo

Of course the File with 100% similarity would be the file I would have obtained with `find / -name 'hello'`

The reason I want to have something like this is the following: I don't want to have to know how a File is written exactly in Order to find it.

Comment: `sort` does this for typical locale such as `en_US.utf8`.

Comment: I thought about `agrep`, but it doesn't seem have an option for printing the match distance, so sorting by it won't be easy. Though something like `find | agrep -i2 hello` would give everything within two modifications

Comment: @ThomasDickey Eh, I don't think so. Looks to me like OP wants to sort based on unicity distance, and I'm pretty sure stock GNU (at least) `sort` doesn't do that.

Comment: Should files "hello" and "jello" be considered _similar_? Since you've included `hello` and `heo`, it seems that `heo` is not _similar_ to `hello`. But I were looking for `heo` would `hello` be considered _similar_ ? If so, you've got a non-symmetrical relationship between pairs of filenames, and this probably needs to be defined better than just "do what I mean".

Comment: in the most extreme case it would list all files descending by similarity. I would like to have the possibility to limit the search by lets say 10. for example: list all files which are similar to 'hello' sort them descending and limit the output to n. I will try to write such a function. I just thought that something like that would already exist since I can' imagine that when people search for something they want to know exactly how it is written.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
ls -ld -- (#ia1)hello # case-insensitive, allow one error
ls -ld -- (#ia2)hello # case-insensitive, allow up to two errors.
```

Recursively, search hidden files (and in hidden dirs) as well (`(D)`):

```
ls -ld -- /**/(#ia2)hello(D)
```

(note that it doesn't do any *sorting by similarity*, only `ls`'s sorting by name of its arguments).

Comment: I had the same in mind but how does one sort "by similarity" (e.g. if there's a file named `hallo` it will be listed before `hello`) ?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible, although not popular.

I've never really used the tool, but I know what too look for; you might want to try [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

Generally, what you want is so called "fuzzy search", name derived from fuzzy logic. You know *more or less* what you want. The more or less part makes it fuzzy.

I would give `fzf` a try if I were you, but consider other options:

- If you created the file by yourself, and know how it starts, you may use tab-completion to find it(start typing the name of the file, and then press tab to autocomplete/see possible options).
- If you don't really know the name of the file, but know some other data(size, date of creation, etc.) you may search by these quantifiers.

Comment: When I search for 'hello' then it has to me the exactly same semantic meaning as if the file would be named HELLO. The point is in certain situations I want to find what I mean, not what I type since when I have an ssh access to a remote machine where files are written by somebody else and I don't know whether they like to write hello HELLO or HeLLo. This is only a tool for me, certainly nothing I would put in a script.

Comment: @SklogW what you're asking for is now a different problem; If we are after semantic meaning, then it means that if I'm looking for "dog", then "underdog" shouldn't really be matched, but "wolf" or "bulldog" should. Then, we need to add some typos and casing to that, so we could theoretically end up with "bull" as a best match - not only this means that we don't have well-defined scope of the problem, but the very problem might be hard/impossible to solve. Kind of reminds me [xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/1425/). Anyway, I hope that my answer at least helps a little.

Comment: No. I said that a File which is named hello has the same semantic meaning as HELLO or maybe helo when somebody writes it wrong. I don't want a complete semantic analysis just include the possibility that somebody else writes it differently.